# How to add file to RSSItem of PyRSS2Gen?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rss

I use PyRSS2Gen in my GAE application.
How can I add attached file to the RSSItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the way to add it:

```
     PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
       enclosure = PyRSS2Gen.Enclosure(
                                        "http://www.example.com/url",
                                        17176948, # file size
                                        "mime-type"))
```